# Limit in the number of atoms

Tags: erlang, elixir

In Erlang/OTP the number of atoms you can create is limited to 1,048,576, and it's *not* garbage collected. It is stated in the `gen_server` docs that atoms are not garbage collected, but I cannot find out if there is a limit.

Does Elixir have a limit as well? And if so what is it?

Comment: Note that as long as you aren't committing the cardinal sin of dynamic generation of atoms (comes right after murder on the social morality scale for most Erlangers), you will never come anywhere close to this limit. Also, atom garbage collection is in the works. The more interesting question is "What problem are you trying to solve by dynamic generation of atoms?" There are *very* few good cases for this (but there are a few -- most involve metaprogramming, naming generated modules and whatnot).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Elixir runs on the same virtual machine as Erlang, and it's thus subject to the same atom limits as Erlang.

You can check the current limit with `:erlang.system_info(:atom_limit)`, and you can change the limit by passing the `+t` flag to the Erlang virtual machine, using `--erl` to let the flag through to Erlang:

```
$ elixir -e 'IO.inspect :erlang.system_info(:atom_limit)'
1048576
$ elixir --erl "+t 2000000" -e 'IO.inspect :erlang.system_info(:atom_limit)'
2000000
```

However, if you find yourself running out of atoms, you should probably try solving the problem in another way.

Comment: Probably the limits are a bit smaller, if we consider the added modules. Anyhow, the number is insignificant compared to total number of atoms.

Comment: Additionally, one can modify this limit at VM startup using the [`+t` flag](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#+t).